# Install MySQL for Visual Studio at 2019 preview6

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

If I try to install MySQL for Visual Studio at 2019 preview6 the preview version of VS is not listed as install target.
I have tried to copy the extension from 2019 Professional to preview:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Oracle\MySQL for Visual Studio\1.2.9
```

But it was not enough. Is there a way to install it manuelly?

I try to test mysql over EF and .Net5 RC2.
Thx!

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET 5. You don't need to install any Visual Studio extension to work with MySQL and EF Core 5 either. You need to add the proper provider to your project as a NuGet package

Comment: According to: 'https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-binary-nuget.html', you should be right. And I already installed MySql.Data 8.0.22 and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.22, before asking here, but there was no new item at the "Choose Data Source"-Dialog.
So I tried @ my old EF6 DB Test Solution.
With VS2019 Pro +Addin its working its working. With VS2019 Preview6 without addin, its not working with this error: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47463676/80044988-bfd73100-84cb-11ea-8535-df56fa179355.JPG